# Regular expression only for website

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to Regular Expressions.

I need to find just website in some text and I'm looking for a regular expression able to find out strings like:

www.my.home,
http://my.site.it

But this regular expression should not find strings like:

address@my.site.it
or if the website is already inside html tag

```
<a href="http://www.my.site.com/">
  <span style="font-style: normal;">www.mambo-test.org</span>
</a>
```

I tried with this one:

\b((https?://[^ ]*)|(www.[^ ]*))

but it also finds the website in the href and between the tag:

```
<a href="http://www.my.site.com/">
  <span style="font-style: normal;">www.mambo-test.org</span>
</a>
```

and I don't know how except this case.

Comment: What platform are you using? What language?

Comment: If don't want to find the pattern inside element attributes *or* outside them (i.e., between tags, as text nodes), where exactly *do* you want to find them?

Comment: I'm using php and the customers can insert text from cms in a richtext field. Sometimes they insert a link and this is fine but sometimes they insert just text with or not the protocol before.
I think is more clear to replace this text with html link tag and I'm looking for a regular expression to find just this type of text.

Comment: I have replaced the link. Apologies for not understand your requirement earlier. Hope the new link works.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called **parsing HTML code via regular expressions**.

First of all, I can feel your pain.

Second, [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) is explained in detail **why you shouldn't do this**.

Third, if your customers are inserting web links in a rich text editor and they sometimes do it properly and sometimes they don't, well... that's definitely a bad practice and such people should be educated. If they are too lazy to click on the "link" button of a rich text editor, their text will be treated as simple text and not as a link. They will soon understand.

Forth, **which rich text editor are you using?** *TinyMCE* offers a whole set of features and plugins that allow you to pre/post process the text inserted by the user easily. That might be easier than trying to edit that text in PHP.

Fifth, if you still need to do this, you might want to have a look to [this tutorial on how to parse HTML to find links](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/aspnets-website-url-regular-expression-validator/) solves your problem.

Comment: That's great but I need to find also strings without the protocol like this one: www.my.site.org

Comment: I have just test the regular expression. For this input: jodfhsdfhttp://www.my.site.org/fishdfsuidhf    I got this output:    www.my.site.org         . What protocol are you talking about exactly?